# Maven Does Not Find Modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a simple setup.

```
project
 |--> pom.xml
 |--> util
 |--> core
 |--> web
```

I managed to configure everything correctly. I changed the versions to `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, I removed the dots from the project names (maybe Maven is picky without telling me, wrong guess) I changed the snapshot policy of `artifactory` to `never`.

I use Eclipse 4.3, and I verified that I am using the embedded maven version.

What I have is that it does find the parent and I can compile `util`. But when I want to compile the core project, Maven can not find it. It seams from the Debug output that it is looking for it in the local repository.

What do I need to do that Maven can find it right where it is in the other top level file.

All three projects are part of the `<modules>` section within the parent `pom`, and I do not need to use a local reference to the parent `pom` for Maven to locate it.

Comment: I don't understand your arborescence : how many projects do you have ? Your example shows one, but you're talking about three. Also, what is the core project ?
On top of that, could you post your pom.xml ?

Comment: In my case the issue was the directory name. The directory name of the submodule needs to be same as the artifact ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got it right, your pom files should look as shown below.

Take into account the different meaning of referencing between your Maven artifacts:

- by referencing a sub project as a `<module>`, a build of the parent `project` triggers a build of the child
- the reference to `project` as the `<parent>` of a sub project is there to let the sub project inherit definitions from the parent

In many cases you want both directions.

**project/pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>util</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**project/util/pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>util</artifactId>
</project>
```

**project/core/pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**project/web/pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi Jens, the problem got solved. It was related to some problems regarding artifactory. It was set to the policy of always serve SNAPSHOT dependencies which can not work in terms of local build dependencies. Why this became an issue is beyond me.

Comment: Anyway your answer is quite correct so it gets the mark and credits it deserves. Cheers and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

for your root `pom.xml`.

If you wan't to make sure you're offline, you may simply add `-o`, no need to change repositories settings.

```
mvn -o compile         <-- in the project root
```

And this is also a preferred way to compile modules. They usually are not being built separately. However if you want to compile `util`, you do it with

```
mvn -pl util compile   <-- in the project root
```

And same applies to `core` or `web`.